# Strongly compact categories (reference request)

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

The notion of a "compact category" was introduced by Isbell$\color{red}{^{1,2}}$. A locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ is called *compact* when every functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ into any category $\mathcal{D}$ which preserves all (possibly large!) colimits is a left adjoint. Equivalently, every presheaf $\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Set}$ preserving all (possibly large!) limits is representable.

Personally, I find large limits and colimits a bit awkward (but maybe you can convince me why they are important?), and in my research I need a property which is perhaps stronger: Let's call a category $\mathcal{C}$ *strongly compact* when every functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ which preserves small colimits is a left adjoint (and *hence* preserves all colimits). This is stronger because we deal with a *a priori* larger class of functors. Equivalently, every presheaf on $\mathcal{C}$ preserving small limits is representable.

I have done quite a bit of literature research, but did not find this property elsewhere. But it is very natural, in particular in the context of the special adjoint functor theorem, which says that every wellcopowered cocomplete category with a generator is strongly compact. So I suspect that this notion appears somewhere? If not, what name do *you* suggest? An alternative would be "realized-sketchable" since I can show that a category is strongly compact if and only if it is the category of models of a (possibly large) realized limit sketch for which every model is small.

*Edit. In my [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115) I am using the name strong compact.

$\color{red}{^1}$ J. R. Isbell, Small subcategories and completeness, Mathematical systems theory 2.1 (1968): 27-50

$\color{red}{^2}$ R. Börger, W. Tholen, M. B. Wischnewsky, H. Wolff, Compact and hypercomplete categories, Journal of
Pure and Applied Algebra 21.2 (1981): 129-144

Comment: PS: For some reasons I don't want these categories necessarily to be cocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Adjoints to functors from categories of algebras](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927877508822061?journalCode=lagb20) Rattray defines that a category $\mathcal{A}$ has **LAP** (left adjoint property) when every continuous functor on $\mathcal{A}$ has a left adjoint, or equivalently every continuous functor $\mathcal{A} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is representable. This is exactly the dual notion to what I called "strongly compact". So Rattray would probably call this property **RAP** (right adjoint property). He shows that every monadic category over a RAP category is again a RAP category. (He proves the dual version: every comonadic category over a LAP category is a LAP category.)

It is a bit confusing that it is claimed in the mentioned paper "Compact and hypercomplete categories" by R. Börger, W. Tholen, M. B. Wischnewsky, H. Wolff that Rattray actually proves that every monadic category over a compact category is again compact: compactness involves hypercontinuous functors. But probably Rattray's proof can be used in both settings.

Comment: Thanks Martin! This is such a good reference!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are locally small and $\mathcal C$ is small-cocomplete, a functor $F \colon \mathcal C \to \mathcal D$ is a left adjoint if and only if it is small-cocontinuous and satisfies the solution set condition. Therefore, a small-cocomplete category $\mathcal C$ is strongly compact in your sense if and only if every small-cocontinuous functor with domain $\mathcal C$ satisfies the solution set condition. These categories were studied in Ulmer's [The adjoint functor theorem and the Yoneda embedding](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-15/issue-3/The-adjoint-functor-theorem-and-the-Yoneda-embedding/10.1215/ijm/1256052605.full) (see Theorem 13, for instance), but were not given a name. Ulmer did not study the variant where $\mathcal C$ is not required to be small-cocomplete.

The relationship to compactness in the sense of Isbell is described in Theorem 8 (where functors preserving all large colimits are called *supercocontinuous*).

(Thanks to Ivan Di Liberti for pointing out a mistake in the original answer.)

Comment: Thanks. Can you perhaps add the definition of "petit with respect to small presheaves" in the special case relevant to my question? The paper deals with more general objects.

Comment: A category is $\mathcal{C}$ is strongly compact if and only if  every COCONTINUOUS functor satisfies the solution set condition. This makes things different. The notion of strong compactness should be seen as a kind of totality.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: I overlooked that subtlety. Thanks. This isn't quite the right concept.

Comment: I've updated my answer to correct the mistake Ivan pointed out.

Comment: Great! In the first paragraph, do you mean "is a left adjoint"?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I did indeed, thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand the second sentence in your answer, since strongly compact categories don't need to be cocomplete (right?) - they are just complete.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: compact categories are cocomplete and complete (by virtue of Ulmer's theorem), so it seems reasonable to also assume cocompleteness for strongly compact categories (it also seems a natural condition to impose to ask for preservation of small colimits from $\mathcal C$). Ulmer requires small-cocompleteness, for instance. I don't know whether the same results will hold if you relax that assumption.

Comment: Compact categories don't have to be cocomplete, see the mentioned paper "Compact and hypercomplete categories", Example 3.15. (I guess that this example is also strongly compact.) I don't see why Ulmer's paper should imply this.

Comment: Thanks. I had interpreted Theorem 8 as showing total categories to be equivalent to compact categories, but this is not true, because Ulmer's "Yoneda embedding" is really a restricted variant.

Comment: I don't know of any references for the variant without small-cocompleteness!